# Determining font style in PHP

Tags: php, css, string-length

I want to use CSS to define my columns based on the size of the longest string in an array in PHP. I have code that uses imagettfbbox() to figure out the length of a string, but it needs to know the font and font-size. Optimally, I want this to be a generic function that I can plug in anywhere without having to know the font definition ahead of time.

Is there some way, programmatic-ly, to determine the font style info? My preference is PHP, but I will take any solution.

I have seen this question before with no answer, but it was asked three years ago and I am hoping there is now a solution.

Comment: what happens when the user changes the font?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it with PHP (styles are decided by the browser after it receives the PHP-parsed HTML), but you *could* use JS/jQuery to get the font-size, resize columns and split the HTML between them. However, when dealing with fonts it will never be perfect nor the same in all browsers/platforms, so I wouldn't recommend it.

The two most reasonable solutions would be:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp (Native CSS3 solution, not supported in old IE versions)
- http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/ (A jQuery plugin)